# Windows Phone 7.1 SDK Alarm

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, sdk, alarm

I'm trying to create an alarm using the new Alarm class in the Windows Phone 7.1 SDK

I'm able to get it to work but the alarm doesn't seem to be going off at the time i've set.

```
Alarm alarm = new Alarm("MyAlarm")
        {
            Content = "Alarm!",
            BeginTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(seconds),
        };
ScheduledActionService.Add(alarm);
```

Comment: If **the alarm doesn't seem to be going off after the amount of time i've set.** then how do you know that **I'm able to get it to work**?

Comment: The alarm comes up but not after the right amount of time

Comment: What happens? I am able to get your snippet to work - while I did not measure very accurately, my alarm did go after approx 30 seconds when set with BeginTime for 30 seconds hence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [remarks in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.scheduler.scheduledaction.begintime%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) say

> The action will not be invoked ***before*** the begin time has been
>   reached.

*(emphasis mine)*

There is no guarantee on the alarm being called at the exact second specified. I would expect there to be the possibility of the alarm being triggered up to a few seconds after the specified time, but not before.

Comment: so what's the point if it doesn't go off at the right time? Could I set the expire time to be say a second after the time I want. Would it then go off in that second?

Comment: I suspect it's not designed to be used for items which require to the second accuracy. What sort of delays are you seeing?

Comment: Well it seems if I put in a longer time it seems to work better giving me ~2-3 second delay, but if I have an alarm that's as short as 5-10 seconds it could be as much as a 20 second delay. I'm creating a timer app so would like it to be accurate

Comment: @Chris if you've got a repro it may be worth submitting it as an issue in Mango (http://t.co/1uCfJlS). If you're building an app which needs to notify the user after a few seconds then this probably isn't the best way to do it.