# How to alert user of alarm finishing in Windows Phone 7 Mango?

Tags: c#, sdk, windows-phone-7

I have a timer app in the WP7 marketplace and would like to be able to run alarms in the background when the Mango update is released.

I've looked into using the Alarm class, but have found it to not be exact enough. ([Windows Phone 7.1 SDK Alarm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6657211/windows-phone-7-1-sdk-alarm))

What is the best way to notify a user that the alarm has finished if the app is closed in WP7.1 Mango?

Comment: What are your requirements for the timer? What do you mean by "notify a user that the alarm has finished"?

Comment: There is a countdown timer that I want to alert the user when it reaches 0

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the Alarm API is your only option.

The only thing that can run once you app has been closed is a scheduled task and those can only do limited processing at most every 30min and even then not exactly every 30min (can be up to 10 minutes out).  Thats not really going to help you.

Comment: That is disappointing :( how do they expect a decent timer app in the marketplace without this? Especially when they don't have one built in!

Comment: Indeed.  Scheduled tasks go some way in providing some background working.  Unfortunately it means that even with Mango there is still a few scenarios that other phones can handle but can't be done on Windows Phone.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to-the-second accuracy on the notification of the timer running out then you'll need to keep your app running to be able to do this.

Comment: Would this be using background tasks? What would I use to notify the user?

Comment: @Chris No you couldn't do this with Background tasks. you'd be reliant on the app continuing to run. Dependent upon the application this may or may not be appropriate. It does sound like what you're trying to do may not be appropriate on the platform as it stands.