# Reminder alarm after BeginTime

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I want to use the WP7.1 Reminder class, and the alarm of the reminder should start in a specified amount of time (in seconds or minutes) from now. This is part of my coding:

```
Reminder reminder = new Reminder(name);
reminder.Title = "foo";
reminder.BeginTime = now.AddSeconds(5.0);
reminder.ExpirationTime = now.AddSeconds(7.0);
reminder.Content = "sdfsd";
ScheduledActionService.Add(reminder);
```

The reminder comes up, but not at the specified point in time (usually several seconds later). I could only test it on the emulator though, is the behavior on the device different? Or isn't the Reminder class supposed to be used on such a fine granular basis (seconds), but only on minutes/hours/days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSDN documentation says (emphasis mine):[ScheduledAction.BeginTime property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.scheduler.scheduledaction.begintime%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)

The action will not be invoked **before the begin time** has been reached. The time value should be in the device’s local time.

This issue was also covered in [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6657211/windows-phone-7-1-sdk-alarm) thread here.